# How do I return the last value of a column while summing another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that aggregates consumption data up until a certain datetime `@end`. However, I need to also return the last value of another column, Employee, when the rows are sorted by `trans_num` (transaction number). How do I do this?

**What I've tried so far:** I tried to use `SELECT Top 1` but this won't give me the last employee for each item. The table has `trans_num` as the primary key and all other fields are not unique. I can provide any other info as needed.

```
declare @start datetime2 = '7/17/17 05:00:00 AM'
declare @end datetime2 = '7/18/17 05:00:00 AM'
declare @job varchar(12) = 'W000017154'
declare @suf int = 29

select

    t.item
    , i.description
    , sum(t.qty) as sumqty
    , t.ref_num
    , t.ref_line_suf
    , (select top 1

            t.emp_num

        from

            isw_lptrans as t

        where

            t.ref_num = @job
            and t.ref_line_suf = @suf
            and t.createdate between @start and @end

        order by

            trans_num desc

    ) as lastemp

from

    isw_lptrans as t
    inner join item as i on i.item = t.item

where

    t.trans_type = 'I'
    and t.createdate between @start and @end
    and t.ref_num = @job
    and t.ref_line_suf = @suf

group by

    t.item
    , i.description
    , t.ref_num
    , t.ref_line_suf
```

**Screenshot of rows:** The highlighted line shows the last row when the `@end` datetime is specified. So I need to sum the `qty` column but then also return the last value in `emp_num` (Employee column). So in the screenshot below, the total quantity should be 1000 while returning `TG43499` as the last value of the `emp_num` column.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a common table expression ([CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)), and a RANK function, as a subquery that will return the last employee to transact each item?

This query might not work exactly, but it could get you started:

```
declare @start datetime2 = '7/17/17 05:00:00 AM'
declare @end datetime2 = '7/18/17 05:00:00 AM'
declare @job varchar(12) = 'W000017154'
declare @suf int = 29

with lastEmp as (
  select 
    t.emp_num
  , t.item
  , RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY t.item ORDER BY t.CreateDate DESC ) AS rankValue
  FROM isw_lptrans as t
  WHERE t.ref_num = @job
  and t.ref_line_suf = @suf
  and t.createdate between @start and @end
)
select
    t.item
    , i.description
    , sum(t.qty) as sumqty
    , t.ref_num
    , t.ref_line_suf
    , le.emp_num lastEmployeeNum
from
    isw_lptrans as t
inner join item as i on i.item = t.item
inner join lastEmp le ON t.item = le.item AND le.rankValue = 1
where
    t.trans_type = 'I'
    and t.createdate between @start and @end
    and t.ref_num = @job
    and t.ref_line_suf = @suf
group by
    t.item
    , i.description
    , t.ref_num
    , t.ref_line_suf
```

Comment: Ah, darn, I was hoping for a solution that didn't use either a temporary table or a table expression. My endless optimism thought it would be possible to do it all within the same `SELECT` statement. But the tricky part is that I don't have the `LAST_VALUE()` function that exists in newer versions of SQL Server. Thanks though!